# My electric oven surface gets too hot when oven is on. Is this normal?

Tags: stove

The top of my electric coil stove gets so hot that to even leave a wooden spoon on it and pick it up will burn my hands . Is this normal?

Answer (score 1):

- The oven vents from a hole under one of the rear 
  burners. If the hole is obstructed or the bowl is 
  turned the wrong way, the heat will escape through 
  the stove top instead of the vent.
- Are the drip pans covered with foil?
  This will cause the top to get too hot because the oven heat cannot escape.
- Are you using the correct size burner pans?
  If they are too large, they trap heat.
- Are the drip pans dark?
  Always use bright finish pans for less heat 
  conduction.

Comment: Good suggestion about being sure the oven vent is not blocked. There is nothing wrong with dark drip pans. The color has nothing to do with heat conductivity. The color does have somthing to do with "radiance", but the rule is "good absorbers make good radiators", i.e., a dark colored drip pan will absorb heat from a burner better than a light colored drip pan and will get much hotter while the burner is on than a light colored one. This could cause the space under the top to  get hotter. But the hot drip pan would radiate the heat away better when the burner was turned off. Stovetops get hot